# Change selection of TabView programatically using Array itself in ForEach SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, tabview

I have a TabView where I have a ForEach loop for various items inside it and I want to change the selection of the TabView item using a timer which automatically changes the selection index. I am able to achieve it using ForEach loop having either `array.indices` or `0..<array.count` but since it is unsafe to use the earlier mentioned methods so I am thinking to pass simply the array itself into the ForEach loop but while simply using the array in foreach loop doesn't changes the selected index using the timer or other programmatic ways. The user need to do it manually scroll to change the selection. Below is my line of code that i tried, can anyone please point out what I an doing wrong.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var currentIndex = 0
@State var itemNames = [ItemNames]()
@State var timer: Timer.TimerPublisher = Timer.publish (every: 6, on: .main, in: .common)


var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
        ForEach(itemNames, id: \.id) { item in
            Text(item.name).tag(Int(item.id))
        }
        }.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
         .onReceive(timer, perform: {
             _ in withAnimation {
                 currentIndex = currentIndex < itemNames.count ? currentIndex + 1 : 0
             }
         }).onDisappear {
             self.cancelTimer()
         }.onAppear {
             setDemoNames()
             self.instantiateTimer()
             _ = self.timer.connect()
         }
    
}

func instantiateTimer() {
                self.timer = Timer.publish (every: 6, on: .main, in: .common)
                return
}

func cancelTimer() {
                self.timer.connect().cancel()
                return
}

func setDemoNames(){
    let item1 = ItemNames(id: "1", name: "John")
    let item2 = ItemNames(id: "2", name: "Mark")
    let item3 = ItemNames(id: "3", name: "Steve")
    let item4 = ItemNames(id: "4", name: "Peter")
    itemNames = [item1, item2, item3, item4]
}
}


struct ItemNames : Identifiable, Hashable {

  var id:String, name:String;
  init(id: String, name: String) {
      self.id = id
      self.name = name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types have to match exactly

Change your tag to

```
.tag(Int(item.id) as! Int)
```

The above line works because it remove the optional/forces.

**You have to make sure that the `item.id` will ALWAYS be a valid `Int`**

`Int(item.id)` produces a value of type `Int?` because it might fail

You can also do something like below to not force but you might have duplicate tags if for some reason you have 2 ids that fail.

```
.tag((Int(item.id) ?? itemNames.count + 1) as Int)
```

This is very prone to bugs, it only works in a very specific set of circumstances and there is little fallback.

I would switch the selection variable to `String` and keep the `tag` with the original `id` then create a function to pull the next `id` to set with the timer.

No forcing or optionals.

You can also achieve this by making the the `id` and `Int` instead of a `String`

Comment: It is necessary to have the selection variable equal to the tag. Even it is in integer or string the tag and selection variable must exactly unless it won't work